# Unable to remove HTML tags from a string that has a 'aspNetHidden' CSS class

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I am compiling a web user control into HTML and it's returning the HTML with view states enclosed in DIVs with class as `aspNetHidden`. But these DIVs are ruining my page's design and I am trying to remove them using following JQuery code:

```
var c ='<div class="aspNetHidden"><input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="fEButj6b8aiQphz0BrJAJplpNUO1v+7wkyuy4bE4UQ9jy524kYG+mAVtVvxdfpWnKqmCQfVCiHrx21/GiUZe9w==" /></div><div>Code from web user control</div><div class="aspNetHidden"><input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="C21772F6" /></div>';
var $c = $(c);
$c.find('.aspNetHidden').remove();
console.log($c.html());
```

But this code is returning this:

```
<input name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="fEButj6b8aiQphz0BrJAJplpNUO1v+7wkyuy4bE4UQ9jy524kYG+mAVtVvxdfpWnKqmCQfVCiHrx21/GiUZe9w==" type="hidden">
```

Instead of this:

```
<div>Code from web user control</div>
```

Please tell me what's going wrong? And if possible in C# then please also provide me a server side code too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in line `var $c = $(c);`, if you log the initial value of `$c`

```
var $c = $(c);
console.log($c.html())
```

You would see the problem. It just takes the first `aspNetHidden` as `$c` and others are ignored.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3PUMm/11/)

The issue is, whenever you wrap a html string with `$()`, it creates an object with the parent. And your input `c` had just 3 `<div>s` without a parent, so it just takes the first `div` as input and creates an object.

---

**Final Code:**

Try this,

```
var $c = $('<div/>',{html:c});

//or var $c = $('<div'+c+'</div>');

$c.find('.aspNetHidden').remove()
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3PUMm/10/)**

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you want to do ?

You are getting just this, because it is first element in an `$c` array

```
<input name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="fEButj6b8aiQphz0BrJAJplpNUO1v+7wkyuy4bE4UQ9jy524kYG+mAVtVvxdfpWnKqmCQfVCiHrx21/GiUZe9w==" type="hidden">
```

according to this http://api.jquery.com/html/ `$c.html()` 
Get the HTML contents of the **first** element in the set of matched elements

if you want to get this line

```
<div>Code from web user control</div>
```

try this

```
var c ='<div class="aspNetHidden"><input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="fEButj6b8aiQphz0BrJAJplpNUO1v+7wkyuy4bE4UQ9jy524kYG+mAVtVvxdfpWnKqmCQfVCiHrx21/GiUZe9w==" /></div><div>Code from web user control</div><div class="aspNetHidden"><input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="C21772F6" /></div>';
var $c = $(c);
//$c.find('.aspNetHidden').remove();
console.log($c.get(1));
```

Comment: @Aishwarya Shiva I have edited answer, look at it, if it works for you

Comment: Your code is returning `<div>` only. See here http://jsfiddle.net/3PUMm/8/ . Even if it's working how can I get all those tags that are at different index positions? Because my code is dynamically generated and may have this situation.